# Which python IDE would suit better for Multi agent reinforcement learning..?

Tags: python, machine-learning

I am trying to implement Multi agent RL using python IDEs. which one would suit for that?

Comment: Is there any problem with PyCharm..?

Comment: I can't upvote this enough. I have tried many, many, many Python IDEs and nothing comes close to holding a candle to PyCharm. Modern, intuitive, powerful, a joy to work with - and the community edition is free, even for commercial use

Comment: Did you ever find an answer? If so, please either award the answer below, or post your own and accept it. Doing so will help others who read this question in future.

Answer (score 1):

What IDE you use is completely independent of the problem you want to solve (exceptions prove the rule).

That being said, here is a [list of python IDEs](https://realpython.com/python-ides-code-editors-guide/). (More information if you follow the link)

> **General Editors and IDEs with Python Support**
>
> Eclipse + PyDev
>
> Sublime Text
>
> Atom
>
> GNU Emacs
>
> Vi / Vim
>
> Visual Studio
>
> Visual Studio Code
>
> **Python-Specific Editors and IDEs**
>
> PyCharm
>
> Spyder
>
> Thonny